# Is there any query to match starting values of data field and retrieve data in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making an application in which i have to use CRUD operations for car data. The cars data is store in **collection("CARS")** and there are many data fields in a document.

we take a simple example

there are two cars named as **'audi' and 'BMW'** in a collection

If i want to search a car with *CarName* and i Input "aud" in search text box by clicking the search button it will show me a car with a name of `"audi"` by matching its stating characters `aud___` with car name

The solution of the problem i want is

- Is there any query available in firestore which let me get the document by giving its starting characters in search text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that the `\uf8ff` character is a very high code point in the Unicode range and is after most regular characters in Unicode, and write a query like:

```
  db.collection('CARS')
    .orderBy('carName')
    .startAt('aud')  // Looking for aud___
    .endAt('aud\uf8ff')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {...})
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

---

**Update following your comments:**
In the Firebase console, you should see the new index as follows (`carType Ascending carName Ascending`):

[image]

Comment: This is working But one more thing Can we join where() query with it?    Like where('carType','==','auction').    i am using where() with endAT() but it is not working

Comment: The index is created but it is still not working any Idea?

Comment: Do you see any error? It should normally work.

Comment: the error message told me to create index, which i did as following the procedure but after refreshing the browser that error message is still prompting every time i used to run the query and this is my code.  db.collection("cars")
        .where("carType", "==", radio)
        .orderBy("name")
        .startAt(searchText)
        .endAt(`${searchText}\uf8fff`)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) =>
          setSearchCar(
            snapshot.docs.map((car) => ({ id: car.id, car: car.data() }))
          )
        )
        .catch((errorMessage) => console.log(errorMessage));

Comment: Yes by adding index manually it work, but why it was not working before? by creating index through browser

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot answer without analyzing your Firebase project into detail and without nay potential error triggered by the console when generating the index from the URL.

Comment: By the way thanks for your help? a last help please ? can you update the code in which i can match the last characters of car name? i can try but the \uf8ff is a little bit confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230252/discussion-between-usama-abdul-razzaq-and-renaud-tarnec).